# Определить наименьшее значение id из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю выборку из базы.

```
$phta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `idZ` = '$in[id]' ORDER BY `sort` DESC");
```

мне нужно узнать минимальный id записи который подходит под это условие? как это сделать?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно значение колонки `id`, то так:

```
$phta = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(id) AS minID FROM `photo` WHERE `idZ` = '$in[id]'");
$firstrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($phta);
echo $firstrow["minID"];
```

Comment: странно. получаю такой ответ `Resource id #8` хотя в базе под такую выборку минимальный id должен быть **3**, записи с id 8 вообще нет, она удалена была, есть 3,4, ... 9, 10 и тд

Comment: ну так это запрос Вам вернет цифру. Надо еще из запроса достать... Я обновил ответ